# How to relax autocommit in Java JDBC when updating a MySQL database online?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This statement works:

```
Connection m = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imageusers?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&relaxAutoCommit=true", "username", "password");
```

I uploaded my database to a free online website to use wherever and updated my code as follows:

```
Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql9.freesqldatabase.com:3306/serverName","serverName","serverPassword");
```

this works correctly but the message

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
```

Appears in red in the console. I tried to update the new statement with the relax autocommit statement but that gave me a connection error. How can I properly do it so the message no longer appears? The program works but the red exception in the console isn't pretty.

Comment: post complete code

Comment: In your code use `myConn.setAutoCommit(false)`.